# Running Spring Boot "context loads" test in maven causes OutOfMemoryError

Tags: maven, spring-boot, out-of-memory, maven-surefire-plugin, permgen

I have a multi-module Maven project with two modules being Spring Boot applications. Each of them has a simple test that the Spring application context loads successfully (my tests are very similar to [this one](https://github.com/mp911de/testing-with-spring-boot/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/TestingWithSpringBootApplicationTests.java)). I run this tests with the following command in project root:

```
mvn -P IntegrationTests clean test
```

During context initialization things go out of my control, the application "eats" memory (heap size grows quickly to 4 gigabytes) and then the context fails to start with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` error *(yes, I run it in Java 7)*.

Monitoring task manager during testing I noticed that maven spawns two new processes that have something to do with [surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/). I have no idea where it comes from, because I don't add the surefire plugin in my pom.xml.

[image: high load]

Previously when encountered the same error somewhere I specified VM options (`-Xmx256m -Xms128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=128m` for example) and the problem was solved.

This time I tried to

1. set `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable
2. set VM options (when running `mvn test` in IntelliJ IDEA) - it affected main java process but not its children
3. add `-Drun.jvmArguments="..."` in command line

but the problem persists.

Please help me to fight the `OutOfMemoryError` in tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Surefire plugin explicitly to module-specific pom.xml and configure VM options there. I like this solution because this way VM options are

- passed to the spawned surefire processes (which should solve your problem)
- affect only test application builds
- shared between developers in your team
- configurable independently for every module

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx256m -Xms128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=128m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- your other plugins go here -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```